# Непонятный синтаксис скобок в docker-compose файле

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Имеется такой `docker-compose.yml` файл

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: kafka1
    user: "appuser:appuser"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9999:9999"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
```

Что делает выражение `${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}`? Заменяет DOCKER_HOST_IP значением 127.0.0.1 если не задано другое значение? И еще, как правильно называется эта фича?

Comment: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это стандартные shell операции над переменными. В данном случае результирующим значением будет "127.0.0.1", если переменная `DOCKER_HOST_IP` не объявлена (пустая). Подробнее можно почитать, например, [тут](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_03.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Раньше с таким не сталвикался за все время...

Comment: Я уже более 20 лет на кнопки нажимаю и всё равно с завидной частотой сталкиваюсь с "о, я до сих пор не сталкивался с этим..." :)))

Comment: @Игорь, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: @Andrew, да, я знаю, но сразу нельзя принимать ответ как правильный :) тут таймаут вроде 10 минут надо ждать

Comment: окей, просто решил уточнить :D

Comment: Это не shell операции. Синтаксис тот же, но это фича именно docker-compose, т.е. переменные разворачивает не shell, а docker-compose. Почему это важно? Потому, что очень мало из, то что поддерживает shell реализовано в docker-compose, да и то не во всех версиях. Ссылка на доку по shell именно про shell, а там все богаче. Правильная ссылка https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files